# Bootstrap navbar collapse after link click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a boostrap nav menu where the 'Our projects' section is collapsable. When I click a link in the collapsable nav it collapse. However, I would like this to remain open, and collapse (hide) only once a different li is clicked (like "About", "Contact", etc).

Here's the code:

```
<ul class="nav masthead-nav" >
        <li class="active" >
          <a href="{% url 'home' %}" >Home page</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="{% url 'offer' %}" >Offer</a></li>
        <li>
          <a class="accordion-title" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#projekty" href="#">
            Our Projects
          </a>
          <ul class="nav masthead-nav collapse " id="projekty" >
            <li>
              <a href="{%url 'mieszkaniowe' %}" >Appartments</a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="{%url 'uzyteczne' %}" >Public</a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="{%url 'wnetrza' %}" >Interior design</a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="{%url 'biurowe' %}" >Office</a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="{%url 'konkursy' %}" >Contest</a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="{%url 'pozostale' %}">Others</a>
            </li>
          </ul>

          <li>
              <a href="{% url 'about' %}">About us</a>
          </li>
          <li>
             <a href="{% url 'contact' %}">Contact</a>
          </li>
      </ul>
```

Comment: I think we need the javascript code which you have tried :)

Comment: Potentially, that's why it's not working because I don't know how to add the javascript code. I thought it should work like described here: http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#collapse. Can you provide any help with the javacode?

Comment: Yes. I would like to help, we are here to help. But the question does not describe any problem you are struggling with. Just a description of what you want. The url you provided gives a very clear example about the classes you should use and the bit of javascript `enable with: $('.collapse').collapse()`

Comment: Ok - sorry about not being specific enough. The problem is that everytime I click "Appartments","Public","Inter design", "Office", "Contest" or "Others" the accordion collapses. I would like it to remain open, and collapse only on clicking the other, remaining links. As you can see I'm rather new to the topic, so all help is appreciated!Thanks!

Comment: Anybody before I smash my computer?!

Answer (score 0):

The difference between a submenu link is that the href points to '#', so I use the anti selector [NOT](https://api.jquery.com/not/) as

```
$("nav a").not("a[href='#']").click(function(){
...
```

Comment: Why not simply `$('nav ul ul a')` ?

Comment: what if you have deeper levels? are you going to keep updating the script?

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old but I just did this:

```
//close any open menus
    var arrOpenedDivs= document.querySelectorAll(".show");
    for (i = 0; i < arrOpenedDivs.length; i++) {
        arrOpenedDivs[i].classList.remove('show');
    }
```